# Linking tables to extract value based on closest previous date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query

I'm going to use an example that was previously posted but modify it to match my problem:

TOCs bu Date:

```
Location StatDate TOC
WC1  9/1/1900    5600
WC1  10/1/2010   5605
WC2  8/2/1980    4300
WC2  9/5/2005    4280
WC2  10/6/2011   4285
```

Water Levels by date:

```
Location  MeasurementDate DepthToWater
WC1         7/26/2006    5.5
WC1         9/30/2008    5
WC1         10/5/2010    6
WC2         7/30/2010    8
WC2         11/3/2015    8.5
```

Desired result:

```
Location MeasurementDate  DepthToWater   TOC    Elevation(TOC-DepthToWater)
WC1         7/26/2006    5.5         5600      5594.5
WC1         9/30/2008    5           5600      5595
WC1         3/5/2015     6           5605      5599
WC2         7/30/2010    8           4280      4272
WC2         11/3/2015    8.5         4285      4276.5
```

I modified the proposed solution that was previously posted, but that solution didn't JOIN the 'location' fields, and I couldn't get it to work anyway.
I would GREATLY appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Join `Rates` to `Activities` by `(MeasurementDate >= StatDate)` and select `MAX(StatDate)` and `FIRST_VALUE(TOC) OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY StatDate DESC)`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I posted my solution. The one posted above is for the example I used originally:

Comment: Looking at the base data and the desired output... There is the 3rd WC1 row coming from and how does it get the MeasurementDate of "3/5/2015"?

Comment: why this row `WC1         9/30/2008    5` takes TOC=5605 if 2010 > 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [(CROSS) APPLY](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) operator for this purpose. But please have a look at data you have supplied, there is some incoherence in these dates.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TOC (Location VARCHAR(10), StatDate DATETIME, TOC INT);
> INSERT INTO TOC VALUES
> ('WC1',  '19000901', 5600),
> ('WC1',  '20101001', 5605),
> ('WC2',  '19800802', 4300),
> ('WC2',  '20050905', 4280),
> ('WC2',  '20111006', 4285);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE WLEVELS (Location VARCHAR(10), MeasurementDate DATETIME, DepthToWater DECIMAL(5,1));
> INSERT INTO WLEVELS VALUES
> ('WC1', '20060726', 5.5),
> ('WC1', '20080930', 5),
> ('WC1', '20101005', 6),
> ('WC2', '20100730', 8),
> ('WC2', '20151103', 8.5);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     Location,
>     MeasurementDate,
>     DepthToWater,
>     TOC,
>     (TOC - DepthToWater) AS Elevation
> FROM
>     WLEVELS
> CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 
>                  TOC
>              FROM
>                  TOC
>              WHERE
>                  TOC.Location = WLEVELS.Location
>                  AND StatDate <= MeasurementDate 
>              ORDER BY 
>                  Location, StatDate DESC) TC;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Location | MeasurementDate     | DepthToWater |  TOC | Elevation
> :------- | :------------------ | :----------- | ---: | :--------
> WC1      | 26/07/2006 00:00:00 | 5.5          | 5600 | 5594.5   
> WC1      | 30/09/2008 00:00:00 | 5.0          | 5600 | 5595.0   
> WC1      | 05/10/2010 00:00:00 | 6.0          | 5605 | 5599.0   
> WC2      | 30/07/2010 00:00:00 | 8.0          | 4280 | 4272.0   
> WC2      | 03/11/2015 00:00:00 | 8.5          | 4285 | 4276.5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=89d752daf70c8b6f2fd6645b776a660c)*